# NextJs error deploying on ingress nignx: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: docker, kubernetes, next.js, microservices, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to deploy both nextJs and my microservice APIs with ingress-kubernetes. Trying to deploy nextJs on ingress, other services and API seem to work just fine, but my client gives an error of  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'!

[image]

```
rhythm@vivobook:~/Documents/TicketResale$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
auth-deploy-7d794789fb-p9bnc       1/1     Running   0          12m
auth-mongo-depl-7d5bf6f747-zvxwn   1/1     Running   0          12m
client-deploy-5bcbf46c68-56884     1/1     Running   0          12m
tickets-deploy-95bccdfc-26mgx      1/1     Running   0          12m
```

Works just fine on localhost!

My clint.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: rhythmshandlya/client
       
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
  - name: client
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

My ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticket.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/auth(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3001
          - path: /api/tickets(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: tickets-srv
                port:
                  number: 3002
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to?  Do you have any log messages from the cluster?  Does `kubectl logs` show a request is making its way to the backend service, and if so, does it have the correct URL path?

Comment: The url path is correct, I am able to make API calls!

Comment: Unexpected token '<' is usually caused as the browser's reaction to the unexpected top-line <!DOCTYPE html> from the server, usually, but it's nextJs and I don't know how to resolve such an issue!